# What is the best way to escape HTML-specific characters in a string (PowerShell)?

Tags: html, powershell, html-escape-characters

I'm generating some simple HTML with PowerShell script, and I would like to escape strings used in result HTML (since they can contain some HTML-specific symbols).

For example:

```
$a = "something <somthing else>";
```

should be converted to the following:

```
"something &lt;something else&gt;"
```

Is there any built-in function for that?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

There's a class that will do this in System.Web.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
[System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlEncode('something <somthing else>')
```

You can even go the other way:

```
[System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlDecode('something &lt;something else&gt;')
```

Comment: An alternative is to use `[System.Security.SecurityElement]::Escape($textToEscape)`.  Some differences exist; see: https://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/2009/09/23/you-should-use-system-security-securityelement-escape-in-c-to-escape-special-characters-in-xml-and-not-system-web-httputility-htmlencode/.

Answer (score 25):

Starting with PowerShell 3.0, use `[System.Net.WebUtility]` for any of the four common operations:

```
[System.Net.WebUtility]::HtmlEncode('something <somthing else>')
[System.Net.WebUtility]::HtmlDecode('something &lt;somthing else&gt;')
[System.Net.WebUtility]::UrlEncode('something <somthing else>')
[System.Net.WebUtility]::UrlDecode('something+%3Csomthing+else%3E')
```

`[System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlEncode` is the common approach previous to .NET 4.0 (PowerShell 2.0 or earlier), but would require loading `System.Web.dll`:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
```

Starting with .NET 4.0 (PowerShell 3.0) `[System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlEnocde` internally calls `[System.Net.WebUtility]::HtmlEncode`, therefore it makes sense to leave out the middle man (`System.Web.dll`).

Answer (score 3):

$SomeEmail = "user@domain.com"

$EncodedString = ([uri]::EscapeDataString($SomeEmail))

write-host $EncodedString

[Using [uri] ENCODING MAKES IT MUCH EASIER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbbZ3.png)

Comment: Please don't post code and error messages as an image but rather as code-formatted text since none of us can copy, paste and run an image. For more on this, please see why we 
[**Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2275490)

Comment: URI encoding is different than HTML encoding.  URI encoding will encode `<` as `%3C`, not `&lt;` which is what the OP was asking.