# Using semicolon separator csv with Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, parsing

I have to parse CSV file with delimiter semicolon exported from database. Simply

```
$csv = import-csv -Path C:\Users\user\Desktop\bla\file.csv -Delimiter ';'
foreach ($line in $csv) {     
  $field = $line -split ';'  
  echo $field[3]
}
```

doesn't work well because in one of columns I have sample HTML code which I have to use. Field starts with `;<div>` and ends with `</div>;` Between tags I have tags with style atribute so there is lot semicolons. Anyone have idea how to fix or parse file with text?

Few lines of CSV file

```
product_code;active;name;price;vat;unit;category;producer;other_price;weight;description;stock;stock_warnlevel;availability;delivery;views;rank;rank_votes;images 1;images 2;images 3;images 4;images 5;images 6
raz;1;nazwa pierwszego;19.95;23%;szt.;kategoria;producent1;;1;<div style="background-color:#fff;min-width:640px;max-width:980px;margin:0 auto;padding: 30px"><table style="width:100%;" class="mceItemTable"><tbody><tr><td style="width:50%;"><p style="text-align:;font:16px arial;color:;margin:1em 0;">sometext</p></td><td style="width:50%;"><img style="width:100%;max-width:600px;display:block;margin:0 auto;" src="http://domain.tld/image.png"></td></tr></tbody></table></div>;;1;auto;48 godzin;0;0;0;http://domain.tld/image.jpg;http://domain.tld/image.jpg;http://domain.tld/image.jpg;http://domain.tld/image.jpg;http://domain.tld/image.jpg;http://domain.tld/image.jpg
dwa;1;nazwa drugiego;25.95;23%;szt.;kategoria;producent2;;1;<div style="background-color:#fff;min-width:640px;max-width:980px;margin:0 auto;padding: 30px"><table style="width:100%;" class="mceItemTable"><tbody><tr><td style="width:50%;"><p style="text-align:;font:16px arial;color:;margin:1em 0;">sometext</p></td><td style="width:50%;"><img style="width:100%;max-width:600px;display:block;margin:0 auto;" src="http://domain.tld/image.png"></td></tr></tbody></table></div>;12.0000;1;auto;48 godzin;0;0;0;http://domain.tld/image.jpg;http://domain.tld/image.jpg;http://domain.tld/image.jpg;http://domain.tld/image.jpg;http://domain.tld/image.jpg;http://domain.tld/image.jpg
trzy;1;nazwa trzeciego;29.95;23%;szt.;kategoria;producent1;;1;<div style="background-color:#fff;min-width:640px;max-width:980px;margin:0 auto;padding: 30px"><table style="width:100%;" class="mceItemTable"><tbody><tr><td style="width:50%;"><p style="text-align:;font:16px arial;color:;margin:1em 0;">sometext</p></td><td style="width:50%;"><img style="width:100%;max-width:600px;display:block;margin:0 auto;" src="http://domain.tld/image.png"></td></tr></tbody></table></div>;1.0000;1;auto;48 godzin;0;0;0;http://domain.tld/image.jpg;http://domain.tld/image.jpg;http://domain.tld/image.jpg;http://domain.tld/image.jpg;http://domain.tld/image.jpg;http://domain.tld/image.jpg
cztery;1;nazwa czwartego;3.95;23%;szt.;kategoria;producent2;;1;<div style="background-color:#fff;min-width:640px;max-width:980px;margin:0 auto;padding: 30px"><table style="width:100%;" class="mceItemTable"><tbody><tr><td style="width:50%;"><p style="text-align:;font:16px arial;color:;margin:1em 0;">sometext</p></td><td style="width:50%;"><img style="width:100%;max-width:600px;display:block;margin:0 auto;" src="http://domain.tld/image.png"></td></tr></tbody></table></div>;2.0000;1;auto;48 godzin;0;0;0;http://domain.tld/image.jpg;http://domain.tld/image.jpg;http://domain.tld/image.jpg;http://domain.tld/image.jpg;http://domain.tld/image.jpg;http://domain.tld/image.jpg
```

Comment: can you add few lines from the csv?

Comment: As formatted, that file just isn't going to work. Without a text qualifier, you can't reliably tell the difference between a semicolon used as a delimiter between fields vs. part of the content within the fields. Use a different delimiter, or use a text qualifier (typically quotes) so they can be distinguished.

Comment: Column with description will always starts with `<div` and ends with `</div>` regex will not work?

Comment: @tomipnh Yep, regex shouldn't work as well, you might have nested divs in production - surprise surprise. Only a HTML/XML validation can help. I've got you one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be a solution to what I expected but it works well, but it is much easier than a solution with parsing Xml.

```
$strPath="C:\Users\user\Desktop\bla\file.csv"
$objExcel=New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$objExcel.Visible=$false
$workbook=$objExcel.Workbooks.Open($strPath)
$worksheet = $workbook.sheets.item("file")
Write-Host $worksheet.Range("K3").Text
$objexcel.quit()
```

To work requires Microsoft Excel.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a custom parser in this case. Your file is not a valid CSV because it does not have string delimiters wrapping the data (although it's hard to correctly wrap a HTML, you might first HTML-escape it, then wrap with quotes then separate with commas/semicolons). If you are creating such a file yourself, consider using [`[System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlEncode()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082217/what-is-the-best-way-to-escape-html-specific-characters-in-a-string-powershell) to perform escaping of HTML characters. If not, and you need to parse this file, you will need to join the parts of the string that are mistakingly split by semicolons - but of course, raw call to `Import-CSV` will not work, and you'll have to simulate its functionality.

```
function Import-XMLCSV {
    Param($text,[char]$delimiter=',')
    $columns, $splitText=$text.split("`r`n") # we need lines, not full string
    # also this neat trick splits first line off the rest of text
    $columns= $columns.split($delimiter) 
    $splitText | foreach {
        $splits=@{}
        $splitLine=$_.split($delimiter) # split line normally
        $index=0
        $propIndex=0
        $value=""
        $tag=""
        while ($index -lt $splitLine.length) {
            if ($value -ne "") { $value+=$delimiter }
            if ($splitLine[$index] -match "^<([a-zA-Z0-9]+)") { $tag = $matches[1] }
            $value+=$splitLine[$index]
            if ($tag -eq "") {
                # no tag found, put full string in this property
                $splits[$columns[$propIndex]]=$value
                $value=""
                $propIndex+=1
            } else {
                if ($splitLine[$index] -match "/${tag}") {
                    # if there's a corresponding tag in this piece
                    # check valid XML in here, if not, continue
                    try {
                        $xml = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
                        $xml.LoadXml($value)
                        # throws exception if not a valid XML, so won't save if unpaired
                        $splits[$columns[$propIndex]]=$value
                        $value=""
                        $propIndex+=1
                        $tag=""
                    }
                    catch [System.Xml.XmlException] {
                        # no action
                        write-debug "$index $propIndex $tag $value"
                        write-debug $_.exception
                    }
                } # if matches /tag
            } # if not matches /tag, continue adding to $value
            $index+=1
        } # end while
        # past this, we've got hash table populated
        New-Object PSCustomObject -Property $splits # return prepared object
    } # end foreach splittext
}
```

This code works with restrictions (see below).

Note though, if you don't have a valid XML or a string in either of your fields, you will result in wrong output. Primarily, the trouble with your sample data is in your `<img>` tags, they aren't closed as is demanded by XML standard. To resolve, change them like so: `<img style="..." src="..." />` - the last slash indicates immediate tag closure. Otherwise XML validation fails and you don't get "description" populated. XML validation in this code is a test in case there would be nested starting tags, say `<div>...<div>...</div>...</div>` so that building of the string won't stop after encountering the first `</div>`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below script to convert `comma/semi-column/pipe` separated or any other symbol delimited values to different columns in Excel. Save this as a `.ps1` file.

```
$executingPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
$inputCSV = $executingPath + "\InputFileName.txt"
$outputXLSX = $executingPath + "\Output.xlsx"
$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application 
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add(1)
$worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.Item(1)
$TxtConnector = ("TEXT;" + $inputCSV)
$Connector = $worksheet.QueryTables.add($TxtConnector,$worksheet.Range("A1"))
$query = $worksheet.QueryTables.item($Connector.name)
$query.TextFileOtherDelimiter = $Excel.Application.International(5)
$query.TextFileParseType  = 1
$query.TextFileColumnDataTypes = ,2 * $worksheet.Cells.Columns.Count
$query.AdjustColumnWidth = 1
$query.Refresh()
$query.Delete()
$Workbook.SaveAs($outputXLSX,51)
$excel.Quit()
```

Place the input file where the script file is placed and run the script. The output excel file will be generated in the same location.

By default, Windows will have a default separator according to the region. For example, it may be **comma** as the default delimiter. If you want to change to **semi-column**, follow the below steps.

Go to `Control Panel` and click on `Region and Language`. A window will open. Click on `Additional Settings`.

[image]

Now another window will open. Change the symbol in the `List Separator` section to the desired symbol(for example semi-column) and click apply.

[image]

Run the script. It will create an excel files and the columns in the excel file will be generated on the basis of semi-column.

Comment: You can also just set `$query.TextFileOtherDelimiter = ';'`.