# Is there a better way to convert all control characters to entities in PowerShell 5?

Tags: powershell

Context: Azure, Windows Server 2012, PowerShell 5

I've got the following code to convert all control characters (ascii and unicode whitespace other than \x20 itself) to their ampersand-hash equivalents.

```
function ConvertTo-AmpersandHash {
  param ([Parameter(Mandatory)][String]$Value)
  # there's got to be a better way of doing this. 
  $AMPERHASH = '&#'
  $SEMICOLON = ';'
  for ($i = 0x0; $i -lt 0x20; $i++) { 
    $value = $value -replace [char]$i,($AMPERHASH + $i + $SEMICOLON) 
  }
  for ($i = 0x7f; $i -le 0xa0; $i++) { 
    $value = $value -replace [char]$i,($AMPERHASH + $i + $SEMICOLON) 
  }
  return $Value 
}
```

As can be seen by the embedded comment, I'm sure there's a better way to do this. As it stands, one does some 65 iterations for each incoming string. Would regular expressions work better/faster?

*LATER*

```
 -replace '([\x00-\x1f\x7f-\xa0])',('&#' + [byte][char]$1  + ';')
```

looks promising but the $1 is evaluating to zero all the time, giving me `&#0;` all the time.

*LATER STILL*

Thinking that `-replace` couldn't internally iterate, I came up with

```
$t = [char]0 + [char]1 + [char]2 + [char]3 + [char]4 + [char]5 + [char]6
$r = '([\x00-\x1f\x7f-\xa0])'
while ($t -match [regex]$r) {
  $t = $t -replace [regex]$r, ('&#' + [byte][char]$1  + ';')
}
echo $t
```

However out of that I still get

```
&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;
```

*FINALLY*

```
function ConvertTo-AmpersandHash {
  param ([Parameter(Mandatory)][String]$Value)
  $AMPERHASH = '&#'
  $SEMICOLON = ';'
  $patt = '([\x00-\x1f\x7f-\xa0]{1})'
  while ($Value -match [regex]$patt) {
    $Value = $Value -replace $Matches[0], ($AMPERHASH + [byte][char]$Matches[0]  + $SEMICOLON)
  }
  return $Value 
}
```

That works better. Faster too. Any advances on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kory Gill's answer with the library call is surely a better approach, but to address your regex question, you can't evaluate code in the replacement with the `-replace` operator.

To do that, you need to use the [.Net regex replace method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy(v=vs.110).aspx), and pass it a scriptblock to evaluate the replacement, which takes a parameter of the match. e.g.

```
PS C:\> [regex]::Replace([string][char]2,
                         '([\x00-\x20\x7f-\xa0])',
                         {param([string]$m) '&#' + [byte][char]$m + ';'})
&#2;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little unclear to me, and could be a duplicate of [What is the best way to escape HTML-specific characters in a string (PowerShell)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082217/what-is-the-best-way-to-escape-html-specific-characters-in-a-string-powershell).

It would be nice if you explicitly stated the exact string you have and what you want it to converted to.  One has to read the code to try to guess.

I am guessing one or more of these functions will do what you want:

```
$a = "http://foo.org/bar?baz & also <value> conversion"
"a"
$a

$b = [uri]::EscapeDataString($a)
"b"
$b
$c = [uri]::UnescapeDataString($b)
"c"
$c

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
$d = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlEncode($a)
"d"
$d
$e = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlDecode($d)
"e"
$e
```

Gives:

```
a
http://foo.org/bar?baz & also <value> conversion
b
http%3A%2F%2Ffoo.org%2Fbar%3Fbaz%20%26%20also%20%3Cvalue%3E%20conversion
c
http://foo.org/bar?baz & also <value> conversion
d
http://foo.org/bar?baz &amp; also &lt;value&gt; conversion
e
http://foo.org/bar?baz & also <value> conversion
```

Comment: Fair enough. I was wanting to escape whitespace characters other than \x20 (and I should edit my regex above to say \x00-\x1f). I also wanted to escape unicode whitespace characters.

Answer (score 1):

I have one small function which helps me replacing as per my requirement:

**$SpecChars** are all the characters that are going to be replaced with **nothing**

```
Function Convert-ToFriendlyName

{param ($Text)

# Unwanted characters (includes spaces and '-') converted to a regex:

$SpecChars =  '\', ' ','\\'

$remspecchars = [string]::join('|', ($SpecChars | % {[regex]::escape($_)}))

# Convert the text given to correct naming format (Uppercase)

$name = (Get-Culture).textinfo.totitlecase(“$Text”.tolower())

# Remove unwanted characters

$name = $name -replace $remspecchars, ""

$name

}
```

Example: Convert-ToFriendlyName "My\Name\isRana\Dip " will result me "MyNameIsranaDip".

Hope it helps you.