# powershell script replace special character like à by agrave;

Tags: html, powershell

I find lot information on internet about how to replace special caractere but only same issue the personne want to replace by nothing .

It's for an email saved with outlook 2007 in htm .

I want to replace like "

```
&agrave;    à =line 1 in csv
&acirc; â     = line 2 in csv
&eacute;    é 
&egrave;    è 
&ecirc; ê
&icirc; î
&iuml;  ï
&oelig; œ
&ugrave;    ù
&ucirc; û
&ccedil;    ç
```

My ideas it was put all this information in CSV file and then import in powershell .
powershell will load the htm file and check if we have a special caractere like à .

If the answer is yes ,it will be replaced by à who one the same line .

I know to import csv ,use colum 1 or 2 also I know .replace()
I don't know how to replace the word in the same line from CSV .

I am open to use another way but my knowdelege are small .

Also put this does not work 
I put the full code because that's true is more easy for you to helping me .

If you go on bottom you will an example

```
<p style='margin:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt'><span lang=FR style='font-size:
11.0pt;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";color:#1F497D;mso-ansi-language:FR'>Merci
de communiquer ces identifiants à $users, afin de que cette personne puisse se
connecter à sa session .<o:p></o:p></span></p>
```

and I have this

```
    <html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"
xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882"
xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

<head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<meta name=ProgId content=Word.Document>
<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 14">
<meta name=Originator content="Microsoft Word 14">
<link rel=File-List href="filelist.xml">
<link rel=Edit-Time-Data href="editdata.mso">
<link rel=themeData href="themedata.thmx">
<link rel=colorSchemeMapping href="colorschememapping.xml">
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <w:WordDocument>
  <w:Zoom>0</w:Zoom>
  <w:TrackMoves/>
  <w:TrackFormatting/>
  <w:ValidateAgainstSchemas/>
  <w:SaveIfXMLInvalid>false</w:SaveIfXMLInvalid>
  <w:IgnoreMixedContent>false</w:IgnoreMixedContent>
  <w:AlwaysShowPlaceholderText>false</w:AlwaysShowPlaceholderText>
  <w:DoNotPromoteQF/>
  <w:LidThemeOther>EN-US</w:LidThemeOther>
  <w:LidThemeAsian>X-NONE</w:LidThemeAsian>
  <w:LidThemeComplexScript>X-NONE</w:LidThemeComplexScript>
  <w:Compatibility>
   <w:DoNotExpandShiftReturn/>
   <w:BreakWrappedTables/>
   <w:SplitPgBreakAndParaMark/>
   <w:EnableOpenTypeKerning/>
  </w:Compatibility>
  <w:BrowserLevel>MicrosoftInternetExplorer4</w:BrowserLevel>
  <m:mathPr>
   <m:mathFont m:val="Cambria Math"/>
   <m:brkBin m:val="before"/>
   <m:brkBinSub m:val="&#45;-"/>
   <m:smallFrac m:val="off"/>
   <m:dispDef/>
   <m:lMargin m:val="0"/>
   <m:rMargin m:val="0"/>
   <m:defJc m:val="centerGroup"/>
   <m:wrapIndent m:val="1440"/>
   <m:intLim m:val="subSup"/>
   <m:naryLim m:val="undOvr"/>
  </m:mathPr></w:WordDocument>
</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <w:LatentStyles DefLockedState="false" DefUnhideWhenUsed="true"
  DefSemiHidden="true" DefQFormat="false" DefPriority="99"
  LatentStyleCount="267">
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="0" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="Normal"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="heading 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" QFormat="true" Name="heading 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" QFormat="true" Name="heading 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" QFormat="true" Name="heading 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" QFormat="true" Name="heading 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" QFormat="true" Name="heading 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" QFormat="true" Name="heading 7"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" QFormat="true" Name="heading 8"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" QFormat="true" Name="heading 9"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="39" Name="toc 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="39" Name="toc 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="39" Name="toc 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="39" Name="toc 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="39" Name="toc 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="39" Name="toc 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="39" Name="toc 7"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="39" Name="toc 8"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="39" Name="toc 9"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="35" QFormat="true" Name="caption"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="10" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="Title"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="1" Name="Default Paragraph Font"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="11" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="Subtitle"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="22" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="Strong"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="20" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="Emphasis"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="59" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Table Grid"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Placeholder Text"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="1" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="No Spacing"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="60" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light Shading"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="61" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light List"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="62" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light Grid"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="63" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Shading 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="64" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Shading 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="65" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium List 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="66" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium List 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="67" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="68" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="69" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="70" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Dark List"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="71" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful Shading"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="72" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful List"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="73" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful Grid"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="60" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light Shading Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="61" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light List Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="62" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light Grid Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="63" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Shading 1 Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="64" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Shading 2 Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="65" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium List 1 Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Revision"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="34" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="List Paragraph"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="29" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="Quote"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="30" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="Intense Quote"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="66" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium List 2 Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="67" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 1 Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="68" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 2 Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="69" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 3 Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="70" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Dark List Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="71" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful Shading Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="72" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful List Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="73" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful Grid Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="60" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light Shading Accent 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="61" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light List Accent 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="62" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light Grid Accent 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="63" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Shading 1 Accent 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="64" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Shading 2 Accent 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="65" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium List 1 Accent 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="66" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium List 2 Accent 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="67" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 1 Accent 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="68" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 2 Accent 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="69" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 3 Accent 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="70" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Dark List Accent 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="71" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful Shading Accent 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="72" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful List Accent 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="73" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful Grid Accent 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="60" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light Shading Accent 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="61" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light List Accent 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="62" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light Grid Accent 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="63" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Shading 1 Accent 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="64" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Shading 2 Accent 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="65" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium List 1 Accent 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="66" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium List 2 Accent 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="67" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 1 Accent 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="68" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 2 Accent 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="69" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 3 Accent 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="70" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Dark List Accent 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="71" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful Shading Accent 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="72" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful List Accent 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="73" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful Grid Accent 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="60" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light Shading Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="61" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light List Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="62" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light Grid Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="63" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Shading 1 Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="64" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Shading 2 Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="65" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium List 1 Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="66" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium List 2 Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="67" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 1 Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="68" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 2 Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="69" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 3 Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="70" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Dark List Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="71" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful Shading Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="72" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful List Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="73" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful Grid Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="60" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light Shading Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="61" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light List Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="62" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light Grid Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="63" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Shading 1 Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="64" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Shading 2 Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="65" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium List 1 Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="66" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium List 2 Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="67" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 1 Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="68" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 2 Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="69" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 3 Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="70" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Dark List Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="71" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful Shading Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="72" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful List Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="73" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful Grid Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="60" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light Shading Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="61" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light List Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="62" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light Grid Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="63" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Shading 1 Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="64" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Shading 2 Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="65" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium List 1 Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="66" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium List 2 Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="67" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 1 Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="68" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 2 Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="69" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 3 Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="70" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Dark List Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="71" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful Shading Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="72" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful List Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="73" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful Grid Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="19" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="Subtle Emphasis"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="21" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="Intense Emphasis"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="31" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="Subtle Reference"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="32" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="Intense Reference"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="33" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="Book Title"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="37" Name="Bibliography"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="39" QFormat="true" Name="TOC Heading"/>
 </w:LatentStyles>
</xml><![endif]-->
<style>
<!--
 /* Font Definitions */
 @font-face
    {font-family:"Cambria Math";
    panose-1:0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
    mso-font-charset:1;
    mso-generic-font-family:roman;
    mso-font-format:other;
    mso-font-pitch:variable;
    mso-font-signature:0 0 0 0 0 0;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Calibri;
    panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;
    mso-font-charset:0;
    mso-generic-font-family:swiss;
    mso-font-pitch:variable;
    mso-font-signature:-536870145 1073786111 1 0 415 0;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Tahoma;
    panose-1:2 11 6 4 3 5 4 4 2 4;
    mso-font-charset:0;
    mso-generic-font-family:swiss;
    mso-font-pitch:variable;
    mso-font-signature:-520081665 -1073717157 41 0 66047 0;}
 /* Style Definitions */
 p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {mso-style-unhide:no;
    mso-style-qformat:yes;
    mso-style-parent:"";
    margin:0in;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
    font-size:11.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    mso-fareast-font-family:Calibri;
    mso-fareast-theme-font:minor-latin;
    mso-bidi-font-family:"Times New Roman";}
a:link, span.MsoHyperlink
    {mso-style-noshow:yes;
    mso-style-priority:99;
    color:blue;
    text-decoration:underline;
    text-underline:single;}
a:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed
    {mso-style-noshow:yes;
    mso-style-priority:99;
    color:purple;
    text-decoration:underline;
    text-underline:single;}
p
    {mso-style-noshow:yes;
    mso-style-priority:99;
    mso-margin-top-alt:auto;
    margin-right:0in;
    mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto;
    margin-left:0in;
    mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";
    mso-fareast-font-family:Calibri;
    mso-fareast-theme-font:minor-latin;}
p.MsoAcetate, li.MsoAcetate, div.MsoAcetate
    {mso-style-noshow:yes;
    mso-style-priority:99;
    mso-style-link:"Balloon Text Char";
    margin:0in;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
    font-size:8.0pt;
    font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif";
    mso-fareast-font-family:Calibri;
    mso-fareast-theme-font:minor-latin;}
span.BalloonTextChar
    {mso-style-name:"Balloon Text Char";
    mso-style-noshow:yes;
    mso-style-priority:99;
    mso-style-unhide:no;
    mso-style-locked:yes;
    mso-style-link:"Balloon Text";
    font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif";
    mso-ascii-font-family:Tahoma;
    mso-hansi-font-family:Tahoma;
    mso-bidi-font-family:Tahoma;}
span.EmailStyle20
    {mso-style-type:personal;
    mso-style-noshow:yes;
    mso-style-unhide:no;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    mso-ascii-font-family:Calibri;
    mso-hansi-font-family:Calibri;
    color:windowtext;}
.MsoChpDefault
    {mso-style-type:export-only;
    mso-default-props:yes;
    font-size:10.0pt;
    mso-ansi-font-size:10.0pt;
    mso-bidi-font-size:10.0pt;}
@page WordSection1
    {size:8.5in 11.0in;
    margin:1.0in 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in;
    mso-header-margin:.5in;
    mso-footer-margin:.5in;
    mso-paper-source:0;}
div.WordSection1
    {page:WordSection1;}
-->
</style>
<!--[if gte mso 10]>
<style>
 /* Style Definitions */
 table.MsoNormalTable
    {mso-style-name:"Table Normal";
    mso-tstyle-rowband-size:0;
    mso-tstyle-colband-size:0;
    mso-style-noshow:yes;
    mso-style-priority:99;
    mso-style-parent:"";
    mso-padding-alt:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;
    mso-para-margin:0in;
    mso-para-margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
    font-size:10.0pt;
    font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";}
</style>
<![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <o:shapedefaults v:ext="edit" spidmax="1026"/>
</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <o:shapelayout v:ext="edit">
  <o:idmap v:ext="edit" data="1"/>
 </o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]-->
</head>

<body lang=EN-US link=blue vlink=purple style='tab-interval:.5in'>

<div class=WordSection1>

<p class=MsoNormal style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:-135.0pt;tab-stops:
135.0pt;mso-layout-grid-align:none;text-autospace:none'><b><span
style='mso-bidi-font-family:Calibri;color:black'>From:<span style='mso-tab-count:
1'>                                             </span></span></b><span
style='mso-bidi-font-family:Calibri;color:black'>Administrator<o:p></o:p></span></p>

<p class=MsoNormal style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:-135.0pt;tab-stops:
135.0pt;mso-layout-grid-align:none;text-autospace:none'><b><span
style='mso-bidi-font-family:Calibri;color:black'>Sent:<span style='mso-tab-count:
1'>                                               </span></span></b><span
style='mso-bidi-font-family:Calibri;color:black'>Friday, July 6, 2018 4:54 PM<o:p></o:p></span></p>

<p class=MsoNormal style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:-135.0pt;tab-stops:
135.0pt;mso-layout-grid-align:none;text-autospace:none'><b><span
style='mso-bidi-font-family:Calibri;color:black'>Cc:<span style='mso-tab-count:
1'>                                                   </span></span></b><span
style='mso-bidi-font-family:Calibri;color:black'>Administrator<o:p></o:p></span></p>

<p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>

<p style='margin:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt'><span lang=FR style='font-size:
11.0pt;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";color:#1F497D;mso-ansi-language:FR'>Bonjour
$manager ,<o:p></o:p></span></p>

<p style='margin:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt'><span lang=FR style='font-size:
11.0pt;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";color:#1F497D;mso-ansi-language:FR'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>

<p style='margin:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt'><span lang=FR style='font-size:
11.0pt;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";color:#1F497D;mso-ansi-language:FR'>Je
vous contacte de la part du helpdesk suite au contact de $users pour obtenir
les accès a sont compte Windows .<o:p></o:p></span></p>

<p style='margin:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt'><span lang=FR style='font-size:
11.0pt;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";color:#1F497D;mso-ansi-language:FR'>Voici
le nouveau&nbsp; mot de passe Windows pour $users,<o:p></o:p></span></p>

<p style='margin:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt'><span lang=FR style='font-size:
11.0pt;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";color:#1F497D;mso-ansi-language:FR'>Son
identifiant windows est :$ID&nbsp;<o:p></o:p></span></p>

<p style='margin:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt'><span lang=FR style='font-size:
11.0pt;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";color:#1F497D;mso-ansi-language:FR'>Mot
de passe&nbsp;: $password<o:p></o:p></span></p>

<p style='margin:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt'><span lang=FR style='font-size:
11.0pt;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";color:#1F497D;mso-ansi-language:FR'>Merci
de communiquer ces identifiants à $users, afin de que cette personne puisse se
connecter à sa session .<o:p></o:p></span></p>

<p style='margin:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt'><span lang=FR style='font-size:
11.0pt;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";color:#1F497D;mso-ansi-language:FR'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>

<p style='margin:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt'><span lang=FR style='font-size:
11.0pt;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";color:#1F497D;mso-ansi-language:FR'>Toute
l'equipe du service vous souhaite une agreable journee .<o:p></o:p></span></p>

<p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How are the diacritique/unicode characters problematic, don't they get displayed properly in the html mail?

Comment: yes that's my problem your code work fine because he change everything but on outlook I see exactly <o:p></o:p></span></p> <p style='margin:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt'><span lang=FR style='font-size: 11.0pt;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";color:#1F497D;mso-ansi-language:FR'>Merci de communiquer ces identifiants à , afin de que cette personne puisse se connecter à sa session .<o:p></o:p>
I think I am on wrong way because I use send-mailmesssage without any -encoding an my issue could be from this .

Comment: I tried send-mailmessage with -encoding but same issue on outlook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10082285/6811411) to the question [What is the best way to escape HTML-specific characters in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082217/what-is-the-best-way-to-escape-html-specific-characters-in-a-string-powershell) presents a `.net` method to accomplish this and also to reverse it

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
[System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlEncode('something <somthing else>')
[System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlDecode('something &lt;something else&gt;')
```

Sample output

```
something &lt;somthing else&gt;
something <something else>
```

Putting your csv text in a here string

```
$Text = @"
&agrave;    à =line 1 in csv
&acirc; â     = line 2 in csv
&eacute;    é 
&egrave;    è 
&ecirc; ê
&icirc; î
&iuml;  ï
&oelig; œ
&ugrave;    ù
&ucirc; û
&ccedil;    ç
"@

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
[System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlDecode($Text)
```

has this output:

```
à    à =line 1 in csv
â â     = line 2 in csv
é    é
è    è
ê ê
î î
ï  ï
œ œ
ù    ù
û û
ç    ç
```

So there is no need to do every posssible replacement in a loop.

Comment: hello thank you for your sharing ,I will use it .I would like understand the difference beetwen @{} and @"" .I think @{} store command only ? and @"" will store text only ?
I am good ?

Comment: I am sorry but I am little bit lost .So ,If I understood 
$Text mean my HTML because the system to convert from à to &agrave; are already charged/present in HtmlDecode ?

Comment: I'm not shure what direction you want to convert, you have both available.

Comment: sorry when I opened this subject my ideas it was convert from Ë to &Euml; and then I know how to invert with CSV .
I discover your solution and tried lot things .Now I know how to use it ,but I have an issue when I want to try with  outlook ,indeed I show all the code on outlook but not the text .Also your code change everything example from  </html> to &lt;/html&gt; I don't why .

Comment: Without seeing neither your code nor a sample text, it's difficult to advise. If the text already contains html tags which can't be modified a special hash table might work. In [this question the focus in on javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286921/efficiently-replace-all-accented-characters-in-a-string?noredirect=1&lq=1) but helpful.  [Here are UTF8 tables](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl) and [here html entities](https://www.web2generators.com/html-based-tools/online-html-entities-encoder-and-decoder) I'll have to think about it.

Comment: Without knowing which [unicode characters are present](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence) this get's more complicated, I can understand why some people delete or normalize these characters :-(

Comment: I put the full code because it was true you that can't find a solution if you don't have the full code .
also I don't know why outlook 2007 can't auto convert the special character .
I am looking by script because the mail script will take the name from Active directory and some name have special caracter because my compagny work for french people.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the script:

```
# Read in the table of replacements
# CSV file has the following header line:
# html,spchar
# then follows with the & replacement comma
# accented character to be replaced
# This file should be saved as a Unicode file
# or this line will need to be changed to reflect
# the encoding used for the CSV file.
$table = Import-Csv 'HTML_replacements.csv' -Encoding Unicode
# Read in the HTML file
$html = get-content 'Some_Accented_File.html'
# Placeholder for output file name
# Note: This should not be the same as the $html file.
$outfile = "Ampersand_File.html"
#
# Iterate through the replacements file
# and replace the accented characters
# with the &-equivalent
Foreach ($e in $table) {
  $html = $html -replace $e.spchar,$e.html
}
#
# Write the file back out to $outfile file
Set-Content -Path $outfile -Value $html
```

Here is the contents of html_replacements.csv

```
html,spchar
&agrave,à
&acirc,â
&eacute,é
&egrave,è
&ecirc,ê
&icirc,î
&iuml,ï
&oelig,œ
&ugrave,ù
&ucirc,û
&ccedil,ç
```

You can expand this CSV replacements file by reviewing the contents of [this page](http://sites.psu.edu/symbolcodes/ipavowels/)

Comment: I tried yesterday and I was so close but for me 'foreach' is still hard to use it .Thank you. 
Also so many thank you because you explain the code ,so I can  understand and then I will reduce ask question .
I will make an interface and my team can use it .Also I will post the script because if someone want same thing it will be already build .

Comment: The reason my code posts are long is so that more people can understand, sometimes line-by-line what I am doing. I also like to make code more general use than just specifically fixing the one issue. It helps more people that way.