# Send-MailMessage Using HTML File as body changing single quote and dashes to question marks

Tags: html, powershell, sendmail

I'm trying to figure out how to best use Powershell to send email.  I've been struggling with single quote ' and dashes - turning into question marks ? in the sent email and wondering if someone can help.  This is what I have:

```
    ##############################################################################
    $Letter = Get-Content .\Letter.htm
    $From = "Myaddress@email.com"
    $To = address@email.com
    $Cc = "MyOtherAddress@email.com"
    $Subject = "Subject"
    $Body = @"$Name,

    $Letter
    "@
    $SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
    $SMTPPort = "587"
    Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Cc $Cc -Subject $Subject `
    -Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -port $SMTPPort -UseSsl -BodyAsHtml -Credential $Credential

    ##############################################################################
```

I have also tried:

```
    $Letter = Get-Content .\Letter.htm -Raw
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to escape HTML-specific characters in a string (PowerShell)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082217/what-is-the-best-way-to-escape-html-specific-characters-in-a-string-powershell)

Comment: You need to use : `$body = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlEncode($body)`

Comment: The other thing I could conceive is an encoding problem when importing the file, in which case you could try `get-content -Path '.\Letter.html' -Encoding UTF8` but regular dashes should not be a problem so my money is still on HTMLEncode, which will escape html characters that need to be escaped.

Comment: Ugh...  I've tried both of these now and still not seeing any difference with the outgoing letter.

Comment: @SagePourpre it was the encoding.  I thought I had to add the encoding to the $letter variable, but I needed to add the -Encoding UTF8 parameter to the send-mailmessage.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be working for me.

```
$From = "Myaddress@email.com"
$To = "address@email.com"
$Cc = "MyOtherAddress@email.com"
$Subject = "Subject"
$Body = Get-Content "C:\Users\TestUser\Downloads\StackOverflow.html"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$SMTPPort = "587"
Send-MailMessage -From $From -To $To -Cc $Cc -Subject $Subject -Body "$Body" -BodyAsHtml -Priority High -DeliveryNotificationOption OnFailure -SmtpServer 'smtp.gmail.com' -port $SMTPPort -UseSsl -BodyAsHtml -Credential $Credential
```